# Using different Ethereum network in Metamask in different tabs

Tags: testnets, metamask, network

Is there any way to have Metamask use, for instance, the mainnet in one Chrome tab and Kovan in another? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the short term, there's no way to do this, in the long term, MetaMask is interested in doing this, but it's probably going to be a while, I wouldn't be surprised if it was more than a year out.

One way you can work around this in the meanwhile is to use multiple Chrome profiles, and you can have a different instance of MetaMask on each profile, even a different seed phrase, which can be very nice for using multiple networks at once.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, unfortunately.

The way I debug is to use MetaMask on the main network in a normal Chrome tab, and use a local Parity node on a testing chain in a Chrome Incognito tab.

This way you can still have two Chrome tabs on different Ethereum chains.

I hope this helps :-)